# How to bulk execute two updates on the same field?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, bulkupdate

I pull a value from an array and immediately add it back to bring it to the front of the array.

```
await User.findByIdAndUpdate(authenticatedUserId,
    { $pull: { lastVisitedResources: resourceId } },
).exec();

await User.findByIdAndUpdate(authenticatedUserId,
    { $push: { lastVisitedResources: { $each: [resourceId], $position: 0, $slice: -50 } } },
).exec();
```

**Is there a way to execute this more efficiently via a bulk operation?**
I tried [Mongoose' bulkWrite](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-bulkWrite) as well as MongoDB's lower-level [db.collection.bulkWrite](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) but TypeScript doesn't accept the `$pull` and `$push` operators for either of them:

```
await User.bulkWrite([
    {
        updateOne: {
            filter: { _id: authenticatedUserId },
            update: {
                $pull: { lastVisitedResources: resourceId }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        updateOne: {
            filter: { _id: authenticatedUserId },
            update: {
                $push: { lastVisitedResources: { $each: [resourceId], $position: 0, $slice: 50 } }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

prints the following error:

```
Type '{ lastVisitedResources: string; }' is not assignable to type 'PullOperator<Document>'.
  Type '{ lastVisitedResources: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ readonly [x: string]: Partial<any> | { [x: string]: FilterOperators<any> | undefined; } | FilterOperators<any> | undefined; }'.
    Property 'lastVisitedResources' is incompatible with index signature.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Partial<any> | { [x: string]: FilterOperators<any> | undefined; } | FilterOperators<any> | undefined'.ts(2322)
```

I also tried `initializeOrderedBulkOp` **but it has no effect**:

```
const bulk = User.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();

bulk.find({ _id: authenticatedUserId })
    .updateOne({ $pull: { lastVisitedResources: resourceId } });

bulk.find({ _id: authenticatedUserId })
    .updateOne({ $push: { lastVisitedResources: { $each: [resourceId], $position: 0, $slice: -50 } } });

await bulk.execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do using the aggregation pipeline updates syntax, like so:

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(authenticatedUserId,
[
  {
    $set: {
      lastVisitedResources: {
        $slice: [
          {
            $concatArrays: [
              [
                resourceId
              ],
              {
                $filter: {
                  input: {
                    $ifNull: [
                      "$lastVisitedResources",
                      []
                    ]
                  },
                  cond: {
                    $ne: [
                      "$$this",
                      resourceId
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          50
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8fG1svlRXZy)

Comment: Thank you. So the normal bulkWrite functions do indeed not work for what I want to do?

Comment: bulkwrite just executes multiple requests at once, you can in theory still send this one update in a bulkwrite request but there is no real need to do it.
It is not possible to do this with the "normal" update syntax in 1 call, and due to the dependencies of the 2 updates I would not use bulkwrite as it will create a race condition.

Comment: But `bulkWrite` executes operations in order, right? I can't try it out because for some reason, TypeScript doesn't accept the `$pull` and `$push` operators in a bulkWrite.

Comment: I want to use bulkWrite to avoid 2 separate requests to the database. And I prefer it over the aggregate call because the syntax is easier to understand.

Comment: i recommend you just add @ts-ignore on the type errors then.  if not you can define them before the bulkwrite with proper type casting.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I actually tried ts-ignore before but I didn't cast the userId to an `ObjectId`. So it's indeed a false positive by TypeScript.

Comment: Do you want to put the `ts-ignore` in your answer or should I post an answer myself?

Comment: Feel free to post it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, this is actually a false positive by TypeScript. Following @Tom Slabbaert's suggestion, I added `ts-ignore` to the `$push` and `$pull` operators and it works properly:

```
await User.bulkWrite([
    {
        updateOne: {
            filter: { _id: authenticatedUserId },
            update: {
                // @ts-ignore
                $pull: { lastVisitedResources: resourceId }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        updateOne: {
            filter: { _id: authenticatedUserId },
            update: {
                // @ts-ignore
                $push: { lastVisitedResources: { $each: [resourceId], $position: 0, $slice: 50 } }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Note: **If you use the native `db.collection.bulkWrite` instead of Mongoose's `Model.bulkWrite`, you have to cast the `id`s from `string`s to `mongoose.Type.ObjectId`s.**